# How to step into x86 source code in GDB with .data sections?

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb

With the following code:

[image]

Compiled using the following command:

```
gcc -g -lc -m64 -o foo foo.s && gdb -tui ./foo
```

I can step into the `foo` procedure if the `.data` section is deleted, but GDB says `No source available` when I try to `stepi` into `foo` when the `.data` section is there.

How does one make it so they can step into procedures when their source has `.data` and `.rodata` sections?

Comment: Put foo in .text and not .data?

Comment: ...So, that's what that tag is for. ( Thanks. That fixed it. )

Comment: yeah, didn't ever tried to search why it's called `.text`, on some other platforms with other assemblers you can sometimes see `code` segment, but on your platform it's "text" (has probably some logical explanation and historical reasons, but can be a bit confusing). Think about `.text` section as "read only + executable" in GNU gas+gcc world. Also you can put there also data, but only read-only constants ... sometimes used to put small constants near the code which is using them, to make the life of memory controller easier (reading fewer memory pages into caches).